# How to select a group of nodes based on their relative distance to the document root

Tags: ruby, xpath, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have been thinking about this problem for quite a while but I can't seem to find a plausible solution: How is it possible to select a group of nodes based on their relative distance to the document root?

Given a sample HTML fragment like so that has been parsed with Nokogiri:

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Follow us</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Assuming the only thing I know about this document, is that the nodes I am looking for are:
a group of `<a>` tags that have the same relative distance to the `<body>` tag and the highest amount of matches. In the above example that would mean matching the group inside the `<ol>`, because it has the highest amount of nodes that have the same distance to the `<body>`.

Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Comment: Will the `a` nodes always be wrapped in a `li`?

Comment: @JWiley Thats not sure, but if you have a solution for that it might opens up for a way to make it more generic afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

It's an odd need/request, but I'd start with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<body>
  <nav>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Follow us</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
EOT

a_tags = doc.search('a')
            .group_by{ |n| n.path.split('/').count }
            .max_by{ |c, n| c }
            .last

a_tags
# => [#(Element:0x3fe3a6012a60 {
#       name = "a",
#       attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe3a6098750 { name = "href", value = "#" })],
#       children = [ #(Text "Home")]
#       }),
#     #(Element:0x3fe3a6012830 {
#       name = "a",
#       attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe3a6096914 { name = "href", value = "#" })],
#       children = [ #(Text "About")]
#       }),
#     #(Element:0x3fe3a601240c {
#       name = "a",
#       attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3fe3a6070ef8 { name = "href", value = "#" })],
#       children = [ #(Text "Contact")]
#       })]
```

The end result in `a_tags` is an array of nodes that are at an equal distance from the root.

From that I tried:

```
a_tags = doc.search('a').group_by{ |n| n.path.gsub(/\[\d+\]/, '') }.max_by{ |p, n| n.size }
# => ["/html/body/nav/ol/li/a",
#     [#(Element:0x3ff6f10d2c08 {
#        name = "a",
#        attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3ff6f10d1cf4 { name = "href", value = "#" })],
#        children = [ #(Text "Home")]
#        }),
#      #(Element:0x3ff6f10d2b18 {
#        name = "a",
#        attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3ff6f10cc254 { name = "href", value = "#" })],
#        children = [ #(Text "About")]
#        }),
#      #(Element:0x3ff6f10d2a8c {
#        name = "a",
#        attributes = [ #(Attr:0x3ff6f10c3b2c { name = "href", value = "#" })],
#        children = [ #(Text "Contact")]
#        })]]
```

That returns an array consisting of the CSS path (with indexed values removed) and the list of nodes under it. I'm not entirely happy with the use of the CSS path to identify the clustered target tags.

It's possible to walk backwards from a node to the root of the document and add those nodes to an array. Then, using Array's "set" capabilities you should be able to identify exactly which nodes lie under the same parent nodes. I'm not sure how to work around the fact that the `<li>` nodes differ.

Hopefully those should give you some ideas to work from.